# Holomorphic Poincaré conjecture

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry

Is there a notion of n-sphere for complex manifolds so that one could formulate a Holomorphic Poincaré conjecture ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is known that the only spheres which can possibly be complex manifolds are $S^2$ and $S^6$. Of course $S^2$ is known to admit an integrable complex structure as the Riemann sphere, but it is still an open problem whether $S^6$ admits an integrable complex structure. By the [uniformization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem), $S^2$ admits a unique complex manifold structure.

See the theorem on page 212 of May's *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology* for a proof using characteristic classes that $S^2$ and $S^6$ are the only spheres that even admit an almost complex structure. The notes are freely available on his website [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf).