# Poincaré conjectures for other shapes

Tags: geometric-topology

If you replace spheres in the Poincaré conjecture with objects-with-some-kinds-of-holes can you say that every manifold with the same number and type of holes is homeomorphic to every other such manifold ?

Motivation: mainly interested in shapes that answer the question: [Topological shape of sphere-like equations with complex radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151779/topological-shape-of-sphere-like-equations-with-complex-radius) to see if that would lead to a [Holomorphic Poincaré conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151751/holomorphic-poincare-conjecture) for such shape.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "some kinds of holes."

Comment: Whatever kinds of holes that would make the conjectures true.

Comment: Then yes, by definition!

Comment: Perhaps this question can be phrased as "What closed manifolds are characterized by their homotopy type?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my interpretation of your question:

> Given two homotopy equivalent (perhaps smooth) $n$-manifolds $M$ and $N$, are $M$ and $N$ homeomorphic (or even diffeomorphic)?

For $n = 1$ the answer is of course always yes, and the classification of surfaces shows that the answer is also always yes for $n = 2$.

In higher dimensions, however, the answer to the question is in general no.

Already in dimension $3$, we can find counterexamples. For example, one can use Reidemeister torsion to find homotopy equivalent lens spaces that are not homeomorphic.

In dimension $4$, the answer is again no in general; for example by Freedman's classification theorem, there is a $4$-manifold $\ast \mathbb{C}P^2$ homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}P^2$ but not homeomorphic to it (although $\ast\mathbb{C}P^2$ doesn't admit a smooth structure). In fact, dimension $4$ is where you first see a more striking phenomenon: many closed smooth $4$-manifolds $M$ admit infinitely many exotic smooth structures, *i.e.* there are infinitely many smooth $4$-manifolds homeomorphic to $M$ but not diffeomorphic to $M$. I believe the current conjecture is that *all* closed smooth $4$-manifolds admit infinitely many exotic smooth structures. The existence or non-existence of exotic smooth structures on $S^4$ is still open and is known as the smooth Poincaré conjecture.

Higher dimensional examples can be exhibited as well, for example see Novikov's paper *Rational Pontrjagin Classes, Homeomorphism and Homotopy Type of Closed Manifolds, I*.

Note that my interpretation of your question does not admit a complete answer for $n \geq 4$; for such $n$, any finitely presented group is isomorphic to the fundamental group of some $n$-manifold. Since it is impossible to construct an algorithm to tell whether two finitely presented groups are isomorphic (look up the "word problem for groups"), we see that we cannot even classify $n$-manifolds up to homotopy type for $n \ge 4$.

Because of this, topologists ask the following easier question:

> Let $f: M \longrightarrow N$ be a homotopy equivalence between smooth $n$-manifolds. Is $f$ homotopic to a diffeomorphism?

The field of geometric topology known as surgery theory provides tools with which to approach this reformulated question. This is a large field that I don't think I should go into much detail about here. See Chapter 1 of Ranicki's *Algebraic and Geometric Surgery* (available [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/surgery.pdf)) for some basic background on surgery and what it can do.

---

You may also be interested in reading about the [Borel conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture), which claims that any homotopy equivalence between aspherical manifolds is homotopic to a homeomorphism; this is an important open problem in topology.

Comment: My own interpretation of the question is "In sufficiently high dimensions, is the sphere the only manifold $M$ with the property that if $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent, then they are homeomorphic."  Would you happen to know the answer to this question?  +1 either way!

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The answer is no. For example, any homotopy equivalence of closed hyperbolic $3$-manifolds is homotopic to a homeomorphism (in fact, an isometry) by Mostow rigidity.

Comment: I'd forgotten about Mostow rigidity.  Doesn't Mostow also work in higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes, Mostow rigidity holds for any complete, finite-volume hyperbolic $n$-manifolds with $n \ge 3$, so that does in fact give us a negative answer in higher dimensions too.

Comment: On second thought, I'm confused again.  If $M$ is a closed hyperbolic manifold and $N$ is homotopy equivalent to $M$, does that mean $N$ also has a hyperbolic metric?  When $M$ is *not* closed, $N$ can fail to have a hyperbolic metric - take $M = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $N$ to be the Whitehead manifold.  Then $N$ doesn't have a (complete) metric of nonpositive curvature by Hadamard's theorem.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Good point... Perhaps we should stick to closed manifolds then. A closed $n$-manifold $M$ with $n \ge 5$ admits a hyperbolic metric if and only if it is aspherical and $\pi_1(M)$ is isomorphic to a discrete cocompact subgroup of $\mathrm{O}(1,n)$. So in the closed case, if $M^n$ ($n \ge 5$) admits a hyperbolic metric and is homotopy equivalent to $N$, then $N$ admits a hyperbolic structure too. See this paper: http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1990978

Comment: Thanks for the response - I wasn't aware of the paper you linked to!